# Text file getting treated like binary file

Tags: file

I have a script that outputs database interactions.  In QA, one of the queries my script caught turned out to be a monstrous huge thing (200,000+ characters) heavily laden with (what I'm fairly sure are) UTF-8 characters.  (There's a whole lot of escape-via-backslash going on, at the very least.)

The problem is that when one of the text files where this query appears is opened by a text editor, the editor insists on treating it as a binary file.  It happens under both Linux (Kate) and Windows (Notepad, Wordpad).  Is there anything I can do to the file to make sure it gets treated like a text file, not a binary?

---

**EDIT:**  A potential difference.  The text files that are getting handled properly are created by Perl's file I/O, whereas the file that is screwing up Kate and friends is created by a simple "./my_script.pl > output.log" redirect.  Could that be the source of my problem?

Comment: Whats writing the files and from where does the data originate & what does it look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "treating it as a binary file" in Windows Notepad?

Comment: A Perl script running under a Linux environment.  For the most part, the data is perfectly straightforward text, but the piece of data that's giving me trouble starts with '\x04\a\x041234\x04\x04\x04\x08\x03-\z\z\z' and continues in that vein (with ASCII text mixed in) for a good 200,000+ characters.

Comment: I guess I only have direct evidence that Kate is treating this as a binary file -- I get a warning to that effect when I open it. (The Notepad trouble was reported by QA.) However, both appear to be displaying the same behavior -- displaying boxes when they ought to simply literally be rendering ''\x04\a\x041234\'... etc. Other text files with the same data are no trouble at all; I'm at a loss for what makes this particular text file different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an editor like [emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnicodeEncoding) or vim?  Both have support for UTF-8.  [Kate](http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/kate/) also allows you to set the encoding (menu option tools/encoding/unicode).

Comment: vim gives me a different flavor of garbage; '^D^G^D1234' where I expect to see '\x04\a\x041234'. As mentioned in comments above, other text files containing this exact same data don't seem to pose any trouble for any editors I've tried it with. I can't figure out what makes this one text file different.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, I really recommend [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) - available also as [portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/development/notepadpp_portable) - it handles big files quite well, don't even try to open any big file in built-in Windows Notepad ;)

But I don't know if it can help with your case.

Comment: Seconded enthusiastically, but the Notepad user in question is a co-worker, not me. And whatever Notepad is freaking out over is also baffling Kate and vim over on Linux, too.